# Specifying Author in Source Code in a Commercial Product

Tags: documentation, tagging

Usually there is an `@author` tag in API documentation (JavaDoc, PHPDoc etc). Is it acceptable to use this tag on every function you make in a commercial product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author tag may serve two purposes:

1. Claim code ownership
2. Provide a point-of-contact for future code maintenance needs

Purpose 1 may be a legitimate use for *some* projects, but its use must be governed and enforced by the project team. For commercial closed-source project, it is likely that this usage could be *forbidden*.

Purpose 2 may serve a legitimate, yet transient (temporary) need to help establish multiple points-of-contact in **distributed teams that don't normally communicate**. In other words, teams that had broken or non-existent communication channels, and missing some standard software development practices. Putting that information in a project wiki, or ensuring that source control commit history is accurate and accessible to everyone (developers as well as API users), will be a better alternative.

Consult with project lead if you encounter this tag in **existing** code, to see whether it should be kept or removed.

If you see this tag that refers to a person **not in your company**, it may be a sign of improper code appropriation (e.g. stealing code from other sources without attribution and/or licensing), which is a different and much bigger issue.

Answer (score 5):

Heh, I never thought that by using the `@author` tag I was claiming ownership of the code, in my mind it was more of a "if this breaks, blame me" comment. I've long given up on writing such comments though, version control is my preferred way of finding who to [blame when stuff break](https://twitter.com/yrizos/status/207639717007720448).

If you must show code ownership in the legal sense, then have your `@author` tag in the page/class level DocBlock, and don't forget to point to the code's license with the `@license` tag.